# how to call sqlsrv_fetch_array(..) multiple times?

Tags: php

I have a command like..

```
$Res = $db->ExecSQL($sQry, $param); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Res)){
..
..
}
```

and i wanted to call again the

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Res)){
..
..
}
```

without calling again the "$Res = $db->ExecSQL($sQry, $param);"
because it has no result. there must be a reset like pointing it to the first record. but i dont know how. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a php function for setting the pointer try:

```
mssql_data_seek (  $Res , 0 )
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-data-seek.php

Comment: how about if i am using the MSsql?

Answer (score 0):

In 3.0 version PHP driver for SQL use:

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array ($Res, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, 0);
```